# I created a custom archetype for maven in Intellij, but want to delete it

Tags: java, xml, maven, intellij-idea

So i tried to make life easier for myself but did it to hastily and did something wrong. Now i want to delete the custom archetype but don't know how.

i tried looking in the .m2 file and in the maven file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom archetypes are located in the file `UserArchetypes.xml`. You can edit the file to delete the custom archetype.

The file can be found at

- Linux `~/.IntelliJIdea10/system/Maven/Indices/UserArchetypes.xml`
- Mac `~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea12/Maven/Indices/UserArchetypes.xml`
- Windows `C:\Users\ \<user> \\.IdeaIC2017\system\Maven\Indices\UserArchetypes.xml`

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day

Comment: Found mine in ~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.3/Maven/Indices/UserArchetypes.xml on my Mac today (2022-01-18)

Answer (score 1):

For 'Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS' and 'IntellJ IDEA 2020.2.2' the file is `~/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/Maven/Indices/UserArchetypes.xml`. I got a little bit crazy looking for `~/.IntelliJIdea10` or similar that do not exists, in my case.

Comment: i was wondering around for a while. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 and more recent versions of IntelliJ, the Maven folder is located in `AppData/Local`, e.g.:

```
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\Maven\Indices\UserArchetypes.xml
```

Comment: Thanks @chriga for the pointer in the right direction :-)